# running a for loop using command as end index valrible

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to run a for loop in bash where end index is result of a command

```
#!/bin/bash
# Basic range in for loop
for value in {0..$(ls | wc -l)}   
do
echo $value
done
```

But when I run it I see:

```
{0..14}
```

Comment: Brace expansion happens before variable does in bash. that wont work. That question has been asked and answered many-many times in this forum. Use a cstyle for-loop.

Comment: Further, `ls | wc -l` is not a robust way to get (presumably) the number of files in a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `eval` :

```
for value in $(eval echo {0..$(ls | wc -l)})   
do
echo $value
done
```

`seq` is similar to bash's braces, The key advantage of seq is that its arguments can include not just arithmetic expressions, as shown above, but also shell  variables

```
for value in $(seq 1 `ls | wc -l`);
do
    echo ${value}
done
```

By contrast, the brace notation will accept neither.

`seq` is a GNU utility and is available on all linux systems as well as recent versions of OSX. Older BSD systems can use a similar utility called `jot`.

C-Style- pretty and simple :

```
for ((value = 1 ; value <= $(ls | wc -l) ; value++)); do
  echo ${value}
done
```